Measure the significance of differences in internal distances in two groups
I am a linguist studying grammatical variation in 169 female and 169 male Norwegian authors (using a treebank), based on eight inflectional and syntactic properties. The eight properties are eight binary choices between two alternative ways to express a category, called ‘conservative’ and ‘radical’. What is recorded for an author for a given property is the percentage of the conservative choice. Hence it will be a value between 0 and 100. The eight properties thus define an eight-dimensional space in which the authors are distributed. The (Euclidean) distance between any two authors can then be calculated as usual, taking the square root of the sum of squared differences in the coordinates of the points. A striking difference, stable across properties, between the two groups is that the men spread out more than the women in the eight-dimensional space of possibilities, the women clustering more densely, showing less variation in their combinations of choices. I calculate density of a group as the average of internal distances – i.e., by taking the average of each group member’s average distance to the other authors in the group. The graph shows the average distances to other members of the same gender for women and men. The average of the averages for the men is 69 (standard deviation 16.6) and for the women 60 (standard deviation 15.3). A t-test yields significance with extremely high confidence, but – not being a statistician – I have my doubts about the appropriateness of a t-test. The values for the group members are interdependent, so we are testing properties of the gender groups as wholes rather than comparable properties of each member across the two groups. Hence my question is: is there an appropriate significance test for this kind of data – or am I wrong in assuming that a t-test is not appropriate (which would be nice)? Table mentioned in the comments:



AUTHORS
F1
F2
F3
F4
F5
F6
F7
F8




author1
92,1
98
99,2
26,7
71,3
56,8
80
22,7


author2
55,2
73
93,1
6,4
30,9
49,2
37,2
23,8


author3
97
99,7
100
49
99,1
62,8
86
39,7


author4
99,5
98,7
100
6,5
50,3
61,8
51
20,6


author5
23,2
37,9
99,9
5,6
27,2
78,4
57,8
28





Your example data (37, 13.0 vs 27,11.8) does not quite look like proportion (which would be between 0-1, or would be in percentages)? It feels more like counts? You call these "distances"; i.e. count differences between (a) and (b)? So are you doing t-tests on proportions? Or on counts? Or on count differences? Can you clarify (ideally by editing the question), as it changes the applicability of t-tests.

It sounds like you need a mixed effects model: you want to test 'level 2 units' (individual men and women) based on 'level 1 data' (nested measurements from their novels).  You are right that the data are not independent.

Thank you for your answers! jginestet: I have edited my question to make it more clear, e.g. the concept of ‘distance’, and changing the example to the distances within the full eight-dimensional space.

I guess it would be useful if you could share a small snippet of your raw dataset. It doesn't have to be the real data, it's just to be sure people able to answer your question will interpret correctly your textual description of how the data is structured. You can find an explanation here on how to add tables to your question.

@HelgeDyvik Maybe try to edit your question to add the table directly in it (rather than in comments), as it looks like it has some formatting problems in comments.

@J-J-J: The table which I just added to the question shows the top five lines of raw data for the male authors – there are 169 lines. F1–F8 are the eight grammatical properties, where each property can be realized by a ‘conservative’ or a ‘radical’ expression, and the numbers give the percentage of the ‘conservative’ option for each author. These numbers are then interpreted as points on the eight dimensions in the multidimensional space in which the authors are located.

Then for each pair of authors A and B in a gender group I calculate the distance between them within the space by means of the formula mentioned; i.e., for n dimensions v1 – vn, for each variable we subtract its value for A from its value for B (thus finding the distance between A and B along that dimension), square the resulting distance, add together the n squared distances, and finally take the square root of the sum. These are the values shown in the graph: each dot represents an author, and its value on the vertical axis is the average of the author’s distances to the other authors.

I see. Unfortunately,  I can't offer you a solution but I think that one might involve including the counts from which the % come from, rather than the % alone (otherwise you lose possibly important information). I suspect that a mixed effect model, as suggested by gung, might be a good approach. Hopefully others will have additional, more specific suggestions. // As for the formatting, if I were you, I'd really try to include the table in the body of the question (see the "edit" button just under the question and above the comments). It is necessary to add a line break after each row.

@J-J-J Thanks a lot! I did add the table to the question – I hope it is visible.

Are you measuring the distance between percentages (or proportions), or between counts? Doing it on percentages feels wrong. Take a simple case of a 2x2 contingency table; 6/4 vs. 4/6; this is not a significant difference. But 60/40 vs. 40/60 would be. But your "distance" (if on the proportions) would be identical in both cases. That does not feel right...

I am afraid that the fundamental issue with your approach is that you are using proportions, rather than counts (there is one possible but unlikely exception, which I will cover later). I will assume that for each author and each "feature" (eight inflectional and syntactic properties) you have a number of observations where the author used either the (a) or (b) variant. But this number of observations will be different: in one author's corpus, "feature" 3 is used 100's of times, but feature 5 only a handful of times. So your proportions do not have the same "basis" (denominator) and thus can not be used "as is". Imagine that I measure a proportion of 20% on 10 observations, and another proportion of 40% on 100 observations, the overall proportion is not 30%, but 38.2%. Another example: if I compare 2 authors, with both 10 observations, and one has a 40% proportion, while the other has a 60% proportion, your "distance" will be $.2^2=.004$. Another pair, with 100 observations each, and the same 60%/40% proportions will have the same distance $.004$. But in the first case, a 2x2 contingency matrix test will be non significant ($p\approx.3$). In the 2nd case, the difference is significant ($p\approx.002$). To give both the same contribution is not appropriate, because of the difference in sample sizes. Now you could take the proportions, and weigh themt by the respective # of observations, but now you have counts...
There is one exception, which is that for each author and each feature, you scoured the corpus until you found exactly the same number of observations. If that is the case, then the counts or proportions are identical (to a single multiple scale factor). Here you can use proportions, or counts, and will get the same results (to a scale factor). So in all cases, you should use counts; if the exception applies, you might as well use counts, and if it does not, then you have to use counts.
That should not be surprising; after all, for each of the 8 features, you have a binomial variable (a, or b). When dealing with binomial distributions, you use counts...
So you should use binomial tests, on counts, not proportions. For each feature, and for both genders, add all the (a) and (b) choices. This will give you 8 2x2 contingency matrices (rows: M/F, columns a/b). You can now use a Fisher exact test, or a $\chi^2$ test (My hunch is that both will give very similar results, as your total # of observations is large: 169*average_#_observations per author). That also should give you good power. But you may need to use a multiple comparison corrections (MCC) (Sidak? Holm-Sidak?) as you will make 8 inferences. MCC will reduce your power.
Note that a $\chi^2$ test is also somehow a test of "squared distances" (the sum of the distances -in counts!- between the observed, and the expected under the null). So you would be able to look at the sum of squares (SS) as the statistic of interest for your graphs.
But you also may be able to aggregate the 8 features, and reduce all the data to a single 2x2 contingency table. You say that the (a)'s are "conservative", and the (b)'s are "radical". Then you can look at the overall counts of (a)'s and (b)'s, accross all 8 features, between males and females. You now have a single 2x2 contingebcy matrix, which now can be one-tailed and tell you if male/female significantly use more of the "conservative" form. Now this will be an "omnibus" test, simply telling you that male and female authors use different forms (or not). Then you can use the 8 2x2 matrices and tests, to see which feature contributed the most to the difference (assuming there is one). The advantage is that, since the omnibus told you there is a difference, you can dispense with the MCC. Just show a Pareto chart of the p-values, or better the sum of squares (under a $\chi^2$ test) for each 8 2x2, to show which feature(s) contributed the most to the difference between male and female.
Edited 8/31/2024, based on OP's comments
OP's mentioned that my last paragraph (above the Edit) was not relevant to his specific question, which is about measuring the within-gender variability. Point noted.
Reiterating the first issue, that the proportions have an issue, as they do not have the same basis (i.e. the same denominator, which is the number of total observations of a given feature, for a given author).
The 2nd issue is that, under these conditions, these proportions are not identically distributed (i.d.). These being binomial proportions, they are means (of an indicator variable). But these means belong to different sampling distributions, because they have a different sample size ($n$), and hence different variance. So statistics on these proportions are problematic.
The 3rd issue is with the Euclidian distances, as described. As the OP notes, these distances are interdependent (If you arbitrarily change the position on 1 author in 8-dimensional space, all 169 distances change). So this measure violates the independence assumption. Which makes statistics (like a t-test) based on them also problematic. And since the distances are based on the proportions, does it make it doubly problematic?
What is the solution? To use counts, and binomial tests (since this is the very nature of the observations). But can one assess the spread of these counts, by gender? In a way, yes.
The variance of a binomial distribution is directly correlated to its proportion; if the proportion is $np$, the variance will be $np(1-p)$. And the variance is maximal when $p=.5$ (regardless on $n$). So, if you compare males to females, using counts and a 2x2 contingency matrix, if the proportions are significantly different, then the variances will also be significantly different. Moreover, the largest variance will be for the group where $p$ is closest to $.5$. So you can show that one group is more spread out than the other. Moreover, you can explain why that is: that group uses both forms more interchangeably. The other group has more of a preference for one style. So you can reach the same conclusion as with your first approach, but in addition, you can explain whay that is...
Now you can do this analysis globally, accross all 8 features (sum the counts for all (a) choices, and for the total observations, for male and femals authors, accross the 8 features). You will test for differences in proportions (means), from which you can deduct differences in spread (variance). Your sample size on counts will be quite large, so you will have good power. And you can do the same, but separately for all 8 features (it may be that male authors have higher variances for all 8, or 6 out of 8, or ???).
Using counts (as suggested also by another comment) does not suffer from the i.i.d issues (if you assume that Norwegian male authors and female authors are 2 homogenuous populations). Binomial-based statistical test will be prefectly valid, and your sample size will assure good power.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I need to consider this very carefully. Let me just make one thing clear (in case it is not already): In this part of my study, where I am concerned with distances, the categories ‘conservative’ and ‘radical’ are not relevant. I am not trying to generalize over ‘conservative’ vs. ‘radical’ choices for the two genders, but only to find out to what extent the members in each of the two groups (i.e., group internally) are like each other in whatever preferences they make. (cont.)

I would get he same distances if, for one or more given properties, I were to exchange the percentages of the ‘conservative’ variant with the percentages of the ‘radical’ variant. Would you say that absolute frequencies are still as essential? (With very few exceptions the number of observations per author per phenomenon is in the hundreds or thousands.)

(This is becoming too long – sorry.) Why am I interested in which gender spreads more or less in their choices? In a previous study I looked at the possibility of author attribution, i.e., finding the most probable author of a given text among hundreds of authors based on their choices for the eight variables. For ten random authors I found – to my surprise – that each of the five men were identified for two or more of their texts, while none of the five women were identified for any of their texts. It turns out that the language in the women’s texts seems to vary less.

I am now trying to quantify this difference in linguistic conformity. That is why I am measuring internal distances in the two groups. Hence, in this part of the study, ‘conservative’ vs. ‘radical’ is not relevant, just similarity of choice patterns.

I have edited my answer, in response to your comments, and further thinking on my end.

Short comment of limited importance: you write: “was not relevant to her specific question”. ‘Helge’ is actually a male name (unlike ‘Helga’). I am male.

Apologies... Edited...

You are far from the first to make that mistake.
Again thank you very much for taking all this trouble. It is very instructive, and I will follow it up. I may have further questions later.

You are welcome. Good luck!
